# Connect MySQL database to php

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am trying to connect my database to php and currently the code is being produced in the web browser and not displaying the success message. How can I successfully connect my database without this

```
<?php


$user = 'root';
$pass = 'root';
$db = 'sportsday';

$db = new mysqli('localhost', $user, $pass, $db) or die("unable to connect");


echo "connected";




?>
```

Comment: it seems that you PHP script isn't processed by PHP interpreter, but just shown as a plain HTML file. Is the file `*.php` ? You may have to check your Apache `httpd.conf` settings.

Comment: @OlegDubas the file is definetely .php , I have no idea why its showing a HTML file

Comment: Do you have Apache's httpd.conf configured properly? Like, `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php` , etc

Comment: @OlegDubas I am using XAMPP, I have another .php file which is working fine however this one isn't. I think those settings are already fine

Comment: No idea then. It isn't the php/mysql question, your problem is Apache configuration

Comment: Unclear what you're even asking.  Everyone else in the comments seems to be assuming that you mean the browser is literally showing you your PHP *code* on the screen.  Somehow I don't think that's what you mean though.  You need to clarify.

Comment: If that is it, though, make sure you're not just clicking the file. Make sure you're going to it by typing an address in the address bar with `http://` not `file://`

Comment: @developerwjk I have just tried and that has worked so thanks, so simple in the end to fix..

Answer (score 0):

try to change your line:

`$db = new mysqli('localhost', $user, $pass, $db) or die("unable to connect");`

with this  fragment:

`$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', $user, $pass, $db);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}`

it should help to understand what is an issue

Answer (score 0):

If the code is being displayed on the page, it is a configuration issue and not a DB connection issue. The  tags tell the PHP engine "hey, the stuff between these tags should be run as PHP". Otherwise, everything else is just sent to the browser. Something in your configuration is having the contents of the file served rather than sending it to the PHP engine. I would check Apache and also ensure your file is actually a .php file; make sure in Windows you have "show extensions" and it isn't really something like "myfile.php.txt" or something. Also, you could open the Chrome Developer tools, in the network tab, reload the page, and see what the HTTP headers are when you load the page.

Comment: I have moved the code to a different php file where HTML is used and I put the php at the bottom and the message 'connected' is being shown. So it works here. When I create a new file, as a php extension, with only that code it is displaying the code on Chrome, this is unusual